# the difference between two "for loops" to change a list of strings to a list of integers in python

Tags: python

I have a list of string as below and want to convert it to a list of integers.

```
heights = input("Input heights : ").split()
```

I searched and found the solution for my problem, but I still don't know why the code I wrote first doesn't work. What's the difference between the upper "for loop" and the lower "for loop"?

My code:

```
for height in heights :
    height = int(height)
print(heights)
```

I expected to have a list of integers as below:

```
[157, 48, 157, 169, 152]
```

but it still remains as a string list!

True code:

```
for n in range(0, len(heights)) :
    heights[n] = int(heights[n])
print(heights)
```

Comment: If you do `height = heights[0]` and then `height = 5` would you expect that to change `heights[0]`? It's the same reason.

Comment: The variable is not a synonym for the expression that was used to assign it. So reassigning the variable doesn't change where it got its value from.

Comment: The first for loop iterates over the items in the list, which do **not** alter the original list: they are merely copies. The second approaches the actual array indices.

Comment: Have a watch of https://youtu.be/_AEJHKGk9ns it explains what's going on in your first example well

Comment: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](//nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal it's not making a new copy, it's just binding the name to the existing string object.  Me and Pranav have linked to the same talk which explains things nicely

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are giving the integer value to the local variable inside the loop. To understand what is happening, we have to know how that for-loop operates.

```
for height in heights :
# Here the for-loop iterates through every item the 
# list has, and assigns the current item to the `height` variable.

  height = int(height)
  # then it assigns that value int(height) to the local varialbe it has
  # created
```

The correct way is to directly access the values inside the list. You could build a `for` loop to do this by accessing each element individually `heights[i] = int(height[i])` , but Python has built in function called `map`, that does this `for` loop for us.

```
heights = map(int, heights)
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) is more information how `map` function works!

Answer (score 0):

So, in the first loop you took each height loaded it to memory, coerced it to an integer, but did not expressly save it back to the list.

But using the range and  length of heights:

`for n in range(0, len(heights))`

you captured the indexed location in the list and then saved it back into that location in the list heights at each iteration here:

```
heights[n] =
```

In the second loop you altered the list to hold the changed values. In the first python did work, was not asked to save it or display it in the loop so it just disappeared into the ether.

Answer (score 0):

In the upper "for loop" you get a copy of each element of the heights list and convert it to int and put it on the height variable.
actually, the heights list doesn't change and just a new value will be put on the height variable.
but in the lower "for loop" each element after converting to int is put on the heights list again and this will change the heights list data.

if we know the index of each element in the list we can access each element. for example. for example, this code shows the first element of the list:

```
print(heights[0])
```

and this code shows the second element of the list:

```
print(heights[1])
```

In the lower "for loop" "n" variable is a counter for indexes of the loop that it will start from 0 to the length of the heights list
for example in the first loop "n" is 0 and with each repetition, one unit will be added to it.
with this, we can access all of the elements on the heights list and also replace them with changed new values.